# Creating a script to substitute a small file's contents in a placeholder in a larger file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to create a script that will insert a multi-line text from a text file into my index.html.

Here is what I am thinking. Create a file called `testEnvConfig.json.` The content would contain the setting to my test firebase server.

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyALdWxUxt63AwOrj-waTNvZo7_zt8CuMgs",
    databaseURL: "https://bggoplantestdev.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "bggoplantestdev",
    storageBucket: "bggoplantestdev.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "499035393973"
};
```

I also have a very large html file named `index.html` with over 1000 lines of code.  However, there is a single variable in called `$config`

I simply want to run a a script `./configureEnv <env>` that would take the test file as a parameter and substitute the $config variable with the contents of the test file.

So the end result is this:

*** BEFORE*** (in index.html)

```
try {
  var $config
  var fbapp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

**AFTER** (in index.html)

```
try {
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyALdWxUxt63AwOrj-waTNvZo7_zt8CuMgs",
    databaseURL: "https://bggoplantestdev.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "bggoplantestdev",
    storageBucket: "bggoplantestdev.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "499035393973"
  };
  var fbapp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: Maybe the question should be about how to inject configuration to a Firebase application (The answer to that depends on the way you deploy your app, I think the simplest way would be to use an environment variable), I don't think that a bash hack is a good long term solution. in addition, it is a bit confusing  that you have a JavaScript code in a json file...

Comment: You aren't actually asking for any kind of JSON manipulation here -- if you were, we'd need different tools to do it right. However, since what you're substituting into is *JavaScript*, not *JSON*, we're at a place where the dumb/simple string manipulation approach is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the contents of the file into a variable. Then use a here-doc for the template, and substitute the variable where you want it.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
config=$(< "$filename")
cat <<EOF >index.html
try {
  $config 
  // this $config variable would be substituted by the 
  // value of env in the script.
  var fbapp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
} catch {
  // do something
}
EOF
```

The parameter to the script is the name of the file containing the configuration.

Actually, I suggest you take `var config =` out of the config files, and just put the structure. The name of the variable should just be in the template. Then the script would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
config=$(< "$filename")
cat <<EOF > index.html
try {
  var config = $config;
  // this $config variable would be substituted by the 
  // value of env in the script.
  var fbapp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
} catch {
  // do something
}
EOF
```

Comment: Sorry.  it didn't work.  It just prints out the contents between the EOF block

Comment: I made a change to the base question.  Please help!

Comment: @DerekMegyesi, this answer *does* work. You can see it working at https://ideone.com/gxgi1a (though I'm not quite sure about putting the `>` after the `EOF`; more unambiguously correct to put it up on the `cat` line).

Comment: I got it to work . Thanks Barmar and all. Sorry for the silly question